# How to change field value to null for certain conditions in a query?

Tags: t-sql, null

I have a query where I select data from a table using TSQL.  When one of the fields (field1) has a certain value, I want to change the value of two other fields (field2 and field3) to NULL depending on the value of field1.  I've browsed stack overflow and see many answers saying to UPDATE the table like this:

```sql
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyField = NULL
WHERE MyField = ''
```

But Update changes a table, right?  I don't want to change my table data.  I want to change my query results.  Is there a way to change results of a query like I want?

Comment: Show the query you are using. It sounds like you want to use `CASE WHEN END` for those 2 columns you want to return as `NULL` in your `Select` statement.

Comment: I can't post the query in the comments.  It says it is too long.  It's a big query.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the query. That way people who read your question will have all of the information in one (neatly formatted) place without having to read through all of the comments.

Comment: ok I added main query to my question.

Comment: I got my SQL to work using comments below from kreadyf, so I deleted my main query from my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have table field1 | field2 | field3 and you want to query field2 and field3, but in the case of field1 is NULL, these two other field should be also NULL. So in your case:

```
SELECT field1
, CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE field2 END AS field2
, CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE field3 END AS field3
FROM dbo.MyTable
```

Update (1) after clarification in comment:

```
SELECT field1
, CASE WHEN field1 = 'IR' THEN NULL ELSE field2 END AS field2
, CASE WHEN field1 <> 'IR' THEN NULL ELSE field3 END AS field3
FROM dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying but I think my situation is different.  Here is what I'm trying to do in English:  if field1 = IR then I want to change field2 to be NULL.  If field1 not = IR then I want to change field3 to be NULL.  Also, this will be done as part of my main query.  It will not be a stand alone query.  So I am not just checking for NULL valie in feild1 like your query seems to do.

Comment: I see that kreadyf updated his reply to change the check for NULL to checking for IR.  It's starting to make sense to me but I still don't know how I would incorporate this Select into my main query,

Comment: I'm starting to think I can just add the CASE conditions as statements in the Select part of my main query.   Like this:

Select field1, field2, field3, field4, 
CASE WHEN field1 = 'IR' THEN NULL ELSE field2 END AS field2
From MyTable
Where field2 = 'value' and feild4 > 0

Comment: I did test runs just adding the two CASE statements to the Select part of my main query.  Worked well.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. Please upvote and check the answer as resolved so ;-)

Comment: The first example won't work since the correct comparison is [`IS NULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

As described in [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) documentation:

```
WITH Data (value) AS   
(   
SELECT 0   
UNION ALL   
SELECT 1   
)   
SELECT   
   CASE   
      WHEN MIN(value) <= 0 THEN 0   
      WHEN MAX(1/value) >= 100 THEN 1   
   END   
FROM Data ;
```

Or in your case:

```
SELECT
    MyField = CASE
        WHEN MyField = '' THEN NULL
        ELSE MyField
    END
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: I don't see how that will work.  For one thing, if MyField = ' ' it already is null, right?  Also, you are only checking and assigning values to MyField.  I have three fields.  Also, would your query be a sub-select of my main query?  As I said, I already have a query that is doing other things for my result.  I want to do this change to Null values as part of the main query.

Comment: Say you have your table `MyTable` and three fields `MyField1`, `MyField2`, `MyField3`. Say you want `MyField2` to print `'Hello'` if `MyField1` is null... you can do something like `MyField2 = CASE WHEN MyField1 THEN 'Hello' ELSE MyField2 END`, you can repeat the condition for `MyField3`. It doesn't have to be a sub-select of your main query.

Comment: Let's say my main SQL is this:  (Select p.number, p.name, o.date, c.last_name, c.first_name from Products P, Customers C, Orders O)

When c.last_name is "Smith" I want to change c.first_name to NULL.  Are you  saying use something like this?:

(c.first_name CASE WHEN c.last_name = ‘Smith’ THEN NULL else c.first_name)

How would I add that to my main query?

Comment: Meant to say:  Let's say my main SQL is this: (Select p.number, p.name, o.date, c.last_name, c.first_name from Products P, Customers C, Orders O where p.number =123)

Comment: The example from @kreadyf is very similar to yours. Try building a solution from it. If you are still stuck I'll try to give you an exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did test runs just adding the two CASE statements to the Select part of my main query. Worked well. Thanks for the help!

Here are the exact statements I used.  I named the resulting fields Case# and Payee instead of CaseNo and VendorName, because SQL was calling the results CaseNo1 and VendorName1:

CASE WHEN Accounting_Categories.Name LIKE 'I%' then NULL Else CaseNo END as Case#,
CASE WHEN Accounting_Categories.Name LIKE 'I%' then VendorName Else NULL END as Payee